# redirect to page on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to create a simple redirect using angular `ng-click`. But when i click on the button nothing happens and no errors are thrown.

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div ng-app='RedApp' ng-controller='CountCtrl'>
  <button ng-click='clickclick(1)'>
    Click to redirect
  </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('RedApp',[]);

  app.controller('CountCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.clickclick = function ( cid ) {
    $location.path('/page/'+cid);
};
});
```

i just started to learn angular :) can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing location while defining controller. The correct code is given below:

```
app.controller('CountCtrl', function($location, $scope){
    $scope.clickclick = function ( cid ) {
       $location.path('/page/'+cid);
    };
});
```

Comment: I just tried it but nothing happened :( https://jsfiddle.net/7jos4eqn/ Any idea why?

Comment: $liveen Sorry I forgot to mention use window.location for urls outside angularjs. 
window.location = '/page/'+cid;

Comment: what do u mean by "urls outside angularjs" ?

Comment: @liveen If you using ngRoute and are showing different html views according to route then these are angular ulrs others are outside angularjs. Have a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route to know better how to use ngRoute.

Comment: even i add window.location nothing happens when i click :(

Comment: @liveen for me it is working, 
app.controller('CountCtrl', function($location, $scope){
    $scope.clickclick = function ( cid ) {
       window.location = '/page/'+cid;
    };
});

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this that way ?

```
<button ng-href="/page/1"> <!-- or ng-href="#/page/1" if your base contains # -->
    Click to redirect
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This might come in handy :)  Actually im using the ng-click coz based on the value passed there will be some calculations and redirect page changes based on the input. I dont thing that can be done with the ng-href

Comment: as it is an angular component, you're free to use data binding in it, so you can do your calculations

Comment: i just tried this.. It doesnt seem to be working. When i click nothing happens :(

Comment: So you might have issues with your routing

Comment: what would be the best way to test it? I just started to learn Angular